# Signed CloudFront URL for a S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create a signed CloudFront URL for an object in a Frankfurt S3 bucket (using the python library boto). This used to work very well with eu-west-1 buckets, but now I'm getting the following error message:

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
</Message>
...
```

I understand that new S3 locations need API requests to be signed using AWS4-HMAC-SHA256, but I can't find anything in the AWS documentation how this changes the creation of signed CloudFront URLs

**Edit:**

To clarify, the following code produces a signed URL without raising an error ... The error occurs when opening the created URL in the browser afterwards

```
cf = cloudfront.CloudFrontConnection(aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                     aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
distribution_summary = cf.get_all_distributions()[0]
distribution = distribution_summary.get_distribution()
return distribution.create_signed_url(url,
                                      settings.CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID,
                                      int(time()) + expiration,
                                      private_key_file=settings.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE)
```

Comment: What version of `boto` are you using? [SignatureV4 support seems to have been added in v2.13.2](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/c9342baad5ed2da7be76e8498dcae54a5906e486).

Comment: Using the most current version, but the problem isn't about the API request itself (I think) ... but rather the signature in the signed url

Comment: So, to help clarify the issue, does the generated signed url include `Key-Pair-Id=...`? Or does it use `AWSAccessKeyID=...`?  Also, what does the `Server:` http response header say? "Server: Amazon S3" or something else?

Comment: It includes the Key-Pair-Id parameter. I found the issue and it seems to have been related to the Distribution itself rather than the config or the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was actually the cloud front distribution itself. It seems like moving the origin of the distribution which was already existing (for a long time) from an US bucket to an EU bucket didn't work out.

I created a new one with the same settings (except a new Origin Access Identity) and it worked without any issues.